# Extracting certain bits from binary data

Tags: java, binary, extract, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a binary number that looks like this:

00000000 00000000 00000011 00001101  =  781 integer value  = integer name "packed"

How am i able to extract each of those as separate integer values using bit wise in java. Like the following:

```
int a = (function) = 00000000;
int b = (function) = 00000000;
int c = (function) = 00000011;
int d = (function) = 00001101;
```

If you can see what i am doing up there.. I want the first 8 into one integer the next into a second integer and so on.. I think you do this using bit wise in java but i am completely unsure. Any help is appreciated. Sorry but i am completely new to this kind of thing and really need help with this, Thanks! Basically (function) should equal something like this:

```
packed >> 5; (I know this isn't nearly right that is why i am needing help on this)...
```

This question was answered for me 2 days ago and it worked perfectly fine but now it broke... I have NO idea why.. here is the method i used for doing this:

```
public static int getNthByte(int n, int packed) 
{
   // shift the desired bits into the last 8 bits
   int shifted = packed >> (8 * n);
   // and now get those bits
   int masked = 0x000000FF & shifted;
   return masked;
}
```

But when i put this line of code: I get this answer:

```
int x = 781;
System.out.println(getNthByte(3, x)); (Which should give me 00001101, in integer value)
```

I printlns the following:

```
0
```

Why? This was working fine for me yesterday... but i noticed When i did:

```
System.out.println(getNthByte(5, x));
```

It gave me the 3rd bit:

```
3
```

Which was correct...

tl;dr this method was working fine yesterday now it is all messed up and i need help fixing it or possibly it is my error? I don't know.. Yesterday i put in getNthByte(3,x) and it gave me the correct integer value related to 00001101...

Any help is appreciated.. maybe there is something wrong with the method? or is it just me?

Comment: Try getting all four bytes from the function (`n` = 0, 1, 2 & 3). You may find that you're counting from different ends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in Java, you have to deal with binary data, one word should pop to your mind immediately: [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html):

```
final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4); // sizeof(int)
buf.putInt(yourInt);
```

Returning the nth byte is now as simple as:

```
return (int) buf.get(byteIndex);
```

Note that you make the assumption that your integer is in big endian order; fortunately, you re right: this is the case in Java. Always. Whatever the endianness of the underlying architecture.

Answer (score 1):

As written, your function is working and it is producing the right answer. The 3rd byte (starting from the right) is `00000000`. Since you are right shifting the number by 8*n bits, then ANDing it with `0xFF`, you are getting what you wanted.

When you do the right shift with a number larger than 32 (5*8 = 40), it would appear that the compiler takes just the bottom five bits of that number (or if you like, `40%32 = 8`) and does the right shift with that. So `getNthByte(5, x)` is the same thing as `getNthByte(5%4, x)` is the same thing as `getNthByte(1, x)` which shifts the number `x` right by 8 bits, then looks at the bottom 8 bits.

I am puzzled why you thought that `getNthByte(5,x)` should ever return the third byte. How did you get from five to three? Or was it a typo?

I think you have just forgotten what your function did.

Answer (score 1):

You have passed in `3` for which byte you want, but according to your line

```
int shifted = packed >> (8 * n);
```

That will shift 24 bits to the right, so it's getting the *first* byte, not the last byte.

To flip the notion of your byte order, subtract `n` from `3` before multiplying by `8`:

```
int shifted = packed >> (8 * (3 - n));
```

So that passing in 3 will result in a shift of 0 bits, to get the least significant byte (00001101), instead of the most significant byte.

Or, if your line really does represent the order you want, just pass in `0` instead:

```
System.out.println(getNthByte(0, x));
```